# Including a folder and accessing images in the folder

Tags: php, path

I am trying to access to a folder using "include $path" inside a php file.

Inside the folder, it includes a lot of images, and in php, it includes many tags of img that accesses to the images inside the folder.

Is there any way to access to a image's path inside folder using "include"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what include is for.
Include let you include another piece of PHP (some class, some functions, whatever), it is not for 'accessing' some folder.

If you want to see the contents (images) of that folder, try scandir:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Also make sure your webserver has rights to read those files.

On *nix/apache this user is often named www-data (I have seen 'nobody' and 'apache' too as usernames). On IIS it is typically something like IUSR.

Comment: I am trying to give img tag access to the image